# Comprimir arquivos PDF

Tags: c#, pdf

Existe esse site [Compressor de PDF](http://smallpdf.com/pt/compressor-de-pdf) que comprime os arquivos de `300k` em `90k`, Estava procurando no Google e não consegui achar nada relacionado para fazer em `c#`.

Alguém sabe de algum algoritmo que faça a mesma coisa em `C#`?

**Uso de `libs` somente open source.**

Comment: O complexo aqui é que, como esses algoritmos são de intenso interesse comercial, é difícil achar referências que ensinem a escrever este tipo de código. Pelo menos até então não achei nenhum exemplo completamente aberto de código em C# pra isso.

Comment: Também estou na caça de uma library gratuita para compressão de pdf em c# Estou usando o itextsharp mas não comprime muito em relação as libs pagas

Answer (score 1):

O próprio formato PDF tem já (por omissão) um bloco de compressão.
Para fazer compressão extra, por exemplo o SmallPDF vai a todas as
imagens raster nele incluídas e substitui-as por imagens com
menor resolução (144dpi por omissão) que não fica muito mau mas
que é uma operação compressão com perdas irreversível.

Complementarmente podemos reduzir o número de cores das imagens
raster incluídas (mais uma vez compressão com perdas)

Este tipo de intervenção tem de ser bem medida! É este tipo de compressão que pretendes?

Vale usar este tipo de compressão?

Comment: Fiz testes com o `smallPDF` e ele me reduziu `PDF's` de `300k` para `90K`, perda de qualidade quase imperceptível. Os arquivos geralmente são texto. Então sim vale a perda de qualidade, enquanto o que está escrito no arquivo estiver entendível ao usuário.

Comment: @MeuChapeu, será que poderias disponibilizar um par de ficheiro PDF para que cooperativamente experimentassemos várias hipoteses e no final fazias uma resposta de conclusões experimentais.

Answer (score 0):

Realmente sem utilizar o itextSharp vai ser complicado, existe uma outra biblioteca NPOI.XWPF.UserModel, talvez esse código possa lhe ajudar, nesse exemplo o código na realidade diminui o tamanho das páginas, consequentemente diminuindo o tamanho do pdf também:

```
const double scale = 0.5;

using (FileStream inputStream = new FileStream(@"..\..\../inputdocuments/PackingLightBrochure.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    // open the source document
    Document documentIn = new Document(inputStream);

    // create the target document
    Document documentOut = new Document();

    // enumerate the pages in the source document
    foreach (Page originalPage in documentIn.Pages)
    {
        // calculate a new size of the page
        double scaledWidth = originalPage.Width * scale;
        double scaledHeight = originalPage.Height * scale;

        // append a scaled version of the original page to the target document
        Page scaledPage = new Page(scaledWidth, scaledHeight);
        documentOut.Pages.Add(scaledPage);

        PageShape pageShape = new PageShape(originalPage, 0, 0, scaledPage.Width, scaledPage.Height);
        scaledPage.VisualOverlay.Add(pageShape);
    }

    // write the target document to disk
    using (FileStream outFile = new FileStream(@"..\..\output.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        documentOut.Write(outFile);
    }
}
```

Vi esse exemplo neste site: http://www.tallcomponents.com/pdfkit/resize-pdf-pages

Comment: A Biblioteca é paga, tem que ser open source.

Answer (score 0):

Nunca fiz isso, até porque as bibliotecas que uso pra compressão são pagas, mas existe a [Open Source JBIG2 Encoder and Decoder](http://blog.rubypdf.com/2012/07/25/open-source-jbig2-encoder-and-decoder/) que pode ser útil para o seu caso.

[Aqui tem exemplos de uso](http://soft.rubypdf.com/software/lossless-jbig2-encoder-windows-dynamic-libary).

Answer (score 0):

É possível fazer isso via Ghostscript.

No exemplo abaixo estou chamando o executável via linha de comando e passando esses parâmetros.

```
-sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=C:\temp\saida.pdf C:\temp\entrada.pdf
```

Você pode ver a documentação aqui:

http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.16/Ps2pdf.htm

Answer (score 0):

Tente esse FreeOpenSource PDF Compressor:
http://alternativeto.net/software/pdf-compressor/?license=free